# Naive Bayes multinomial model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, naivebayes

For a movie reviews dataset, I'm creating a naive bayes multinomial model. Now in the training dataset, there are reviews per genre. So instead of creating a generic model for the movie reviews dataset-ignoring the genre feature, how do I train a model that also takes into consideration the genre feature in addition the tf-idf associated with words that occurred in the review. Do I need to create one model for each of the genre, or can I incorporate it into one model?

```
Training Dataset Sample:
genre, review, classification
Romantic, The movie was really emotional and touched my heart!, Positive
Action, It was a thrilling movie, Positive
....

Test Data Set:
Genre, review
Action, The movie sucked bigtime. The action sequences didnt fit into the plot very well
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html), `The multinomial distribution normally requires integer feature counts`. Categorical variables provided as inputs, especially if they are encoded as integers, may not have a positive impact on the predictive capacity of the models. As stated above, you may either consider using a neural network, or dropping the genre column entirely. If after fitting the model shows a sufficient predictive capability on the text features alone, it may not even be necessary to add as input a categorical variable.

The way I would try this task is by [stacking](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html#numpy.stack) the dummy categorical values with the text features, and feeding the stacked array to a [SGD](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/sgd.html#sgd) model, along with the target labels. You would then perform [GridSearch](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html) for the optimal choice of hyperparameters.

Answer (score 0):

Consider treating `genre` as a categorical variable, probably with dummy encoding (see `pd.get_dummies(df['genre'])`), and feeding that as well as the tf-idf scores into your model.

Also consider other model types, besides Naive Bayes - a neural network involves more interaction between variables, and may help capture differences between genres better. Scikit-learn also has a `MLPClassifier` implementation which is worth a look.